# How to test behavior of client side UI/Performance along with load test with n users for desktop applications?

Tags: load-testing, performance-testing, desktop-application

I have to perform load test on a desktop application. So, I used visual studio to test load on web server with 100 users then it worked fine & got no error.

But in real time, I got different behavior on the client side when we do the same activity manually while 100 real users are working together & using that application simultaneously. Client side application is getting crashed/hang or getting UI error due to slowness.

Which tool should I use to test load on both server & client side?

Answer (score 3):

I always have used JMeter for Performance Testing. On this question, I think watching this tutorial may help you for client-side performance testing:

https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/client-side-performance-testing-tutorial

Comment: Thanks for your comments. This tutorial only describes client side performance testing of a web application whereas i am looking the same for a windows application. My application is running on multiple desktops & always be in sync with each other. So, i want to see behavior of desktop application when 100 users are concurrently using that application.

Answer (score 0):

Mirco Focus has got two load testing tools that support client-side (web) load testing: Loadrunner and Silk Performer. Those tools are not cheap and performing load testing this way also requires a lot more load generators.

Another option would be NeoLoad, that works on protocol level, but you can use a Selenium client-side test during a load test to measure client-side response times.

A third option would be to use a separate website client-side automated test script that is enriched with measuring of some actions. That that can be run during a load test in another tool.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. above options describes client side performance testing of a web application whereas i am looking the same for a windows application. My application is running on multiple desktops & always be in sync with each other. So, i want to see behavior of desktop application when 100 users are concurrently using that application.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the following combination:

1. [Appium](http://appium.io/) with [WinAppDriver](http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/windows/) for UI/client side of things
2. [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) for server side of things

The reason of not suggesting Coded UI Tests is that [Visual Studio 2019 is the latest version to support them](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/use-ui-automation-to-test-your-code?view=vs-2017) (same for Load Testing Framework, [Microsoft recommends switching to Apache JMeter for load testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/microsoft-recommends-jmeter-and-blazemeter-as-preferred-load-testing-tools))

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Appium with WinAppDriver is used for UI automation. How can i perform load test with it?